# Parsing an XML to XML based on conditions in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, xml-parsing

I'm new to XML and I've been assigned a task to parse one XML to another XML based on some condition. For example:

```
<xml>
<items>
<item file="sms123" files loaded="20" date="22/12/2014"></item>
<item file="sms23223" files loaded="25" date="22/12/2013"></item>
<item file="mms345" files loaded="30" date="22/06/2014"></item>
<item file="sms02821" files loaded="35" date="31/12/2012"></item>
<item file="mms4738292" files loaded="15" date="21/1/2014"></item>
</items>
</xml>
```

This is the xml file, and i need to parse it to an intermediate XML file based on some conditions. The output xml I want is as follows:

```
<xml>
<items>
<item file="sms" files loaded="80" > </item>
<item file="mms" files loaded="45"></item>
</items>
</xml>
```

All I want is to group the file names into a single file name based on the first word and to add up all the files loaded within the group.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

```
public static function getResult(input:XML):XML
{
    var smscounter:int = 0;
    var mmscounter:int = 0;
    for each(var item:XML in XML(input.items[0]).children())
    {
        var fileName:String = item.@file;
        if (fileName.indexOf("sms")) > 0)
        {
            smscounter += Number(item.@loaded);
        }
        else if (fileName.indexOf("mms")) > 0)
        {
            mmscounter += Number(item.@loaded);
        }
    }

    var sms:XML = new XML("<item file='sms' files loaded='" + smscounter + "'/>");
    var mms:XML = new XML("<item file='mms' files loaded='" + mmscounter + "'/>");
    var items:XML = new XML(<items/>);
    items.appendChild(sms);
    items.appendChild(mms);
    var xml:XML = new XML(<xml/>);
    xml.appendChild(items);
    return xml;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. I still haven't executed the above code, because I don't know where to write this code in Flex. Please help.

Comment: I edited my answer, should be more understandable. You give to the function your input `XML`, and it produces desired output `XML` . And since this is `public static function` it can be executed anywhere.

Comment: This code shows an error as follows :
1119: Access of possibly undefined property loaded through a reference with static type String.
It shows an error on this line
       smscounter += Number(fileName.@loaded);

Comment: An Action Script error has occurred which says: TypeError: Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.

Comment: Edited again. Can't test the code at the moment, my environment is not set up.